# Python/Pandas create zip file from csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, zip, compression

Is anyone can provide example how to create zip file from csv file using Python/Pandas package?
Thank you

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use

```
df.to_csv('my_file.gz', compression='gzip')
```

From the docs:

> compression : string, optional
>   a string representing the compression to use in the output file, allowed values are ‘gzip’, ‘bz2’, ‘xz’, only used when the first
>   argument is a filename

See discussion of support of `zip` files [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11413).

Comment: Is this zip or gzip?

Answer (score 22):

In the `to_csv()` method of pandas, besides the compression type (`gz`, `zip` etc) you can specify the archive file name - just pass the dict with necessary params as the `compression` parameter:

```
compression_opts = dict(method='zip',
                        archive_name='out.csv')  
df.to_csv('out.zip', compression=compression_opts)
```

In the example above, the first argument of the `to_csv` method defines the name of the [ZIP] archive file, the `method` key of the dict defines [ZIP] compression type and the `archive_name` key of the dict defines the  name of the [CSV] file inside the archive file.

Result:

```
├─ out.zip
│  └─ out.csv
```

See details in [to_csv() pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Answer (score 3):

In response to Stefan's answer, add '.csv.gz' for the zip csv file to work

```
df.to_csv('my_file.csv.gz', compression='gzip')
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

The Pandas to_csv compression has some security vulnerabilities where it leaves the absolute path of the file in the zip archive on Linux machine. Not to mention one might want to save a file in the highest level of a zipped file. The following function addresses this issue by using zipfile. On top of that, it doesn't suffer from pickle protocol change (4 to 5).

```
from pathlib import Path
import zipfile

def save_compressed_df(df, dirPath, fileName):
    """Save a Pandas dataframe as a zipped .csv file.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
        Input dataframe.
    dirPath : str or pathlib.PosixPath
        Parent directory of the zipped file.
    fileName : str
        File name without extension.
    """

    dirPath = Path(dirPath)
    path_zip = dirPath / f'{fileName}.csv.zip'
    txt = df.to_csv(index=False)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(path_zip, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
        zf.writestr(f'{fileName}.csv', txt)
```

Comment: As written in another answer and in the [help page of df.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), the `compression` argument accepts a dictionary which can specifiy the `archive_name` inside the zip archive. This works only for zip archives though, for gzip you have to use `df.to_csv("/tmp/df.csv.gz", compression="gzip")`.