# Pandas: efficiently write thousands of small files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, save

here is my problem.

I have a single big CSV file containing a bit more than 100M rows which I need to divide in much smaller files (if needed I can add more details). At the moment I'm reading in chunks the big CSV, doing some computations to determine how to subdivide the chunk and finally writing (appending) to the files with

```
df.to_csv(outfile, float_format='%.8f', index=False, mode='a', header=header)
```

(the `header` variable is True if it is the first time that I write to 'outfile', otherwise it is False).

While running the code I noticed that the amount of on-disk memory taken by the smaller files on the whole was likely to become larger than three times the size of the single big csv.

So here are my questions:

- is this behavior normal? (probably it is, but I'm asking just in case)
- is it possible to reduce the size of the files? (different file formats?) [SOLVED through compression, see update below and comments]
- are there better file types for this situation with respect to CSV?

Please note that I don't have an extensive knowledge of programming, I'm just using Python for my thesis.

Thanks in advance to whoever will help.

**UPDATE:** thanks to @AshishAcharya and @PatrickArtner I learned how to use the compression while writing and reading the CSV. Still, I'd like to know if there are any file types that may be better than CSV for this task.

**NEW QUESTION:** (maybe stupid question) does appending work on compressed files?

**UPDATE 2:** using the compression option I noticed something that I don't understand. To determine the size of folders I was taught to use the `du -hs <folder>` command, but using it on the folder containing compressed files or the one containing the uncompressed files results in the same value of '3.8G' (both are created using the same first 5M rows from the big CSV). From the file explorer (Nautilus) instead, I get about 590MB for the one containing uncompressed CSV and 230MB for the other. What am I missing?

Comment: csv files in general compress really well (generally about 80-90%). so you can try zipping them if size is an issue. 3 times does seem like an awful lot though. i'm guessing you are creating thousands of files.

Comment: Hi, @AshishAcharya thanks for answering. I have no experience in compressing files with pandas and then reading from them. Could you please give me some references to learn that?

Comment: [python-pandas-create-zip-file-from-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754165/python-pandas-create-zip-file-from-csv) - not sure if Zip is out-of-the-box yet, but you can use any other of the compression algos mentioned. you can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html on the normal .csv files though if you really need zip.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python/Pandas create zip file from csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754165/python-pandas-create-zip-file-from-csv)

Comment: Link to the doku:  [pandas-dataframe-to-csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv)

Comment: Thanks @PatrickArtner, i read the docs and i (probably) understood how to do it, both write and read. I'll update my answer.