# pandas dataframe export as csv into zip file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, zip, export

I have this code to export my dataframe to a csv with a timestamp:

```
import datetime


dt_string = datetime.now().strftime("%Y.%m.%d_%H%M%S")
df.to_csv('history/df' + dt_string + '.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

and this code to add it to a zip file:

```
import zipfile


with zipfile.ZipFile('history/df.zip', 'a') as myzip:
    myzip.write('history/df' + dt_string + '.csv')
```

I can then delete the *.csv after.

Is there any way I can skip all the middle steps and directly export a dataframe as a csv file into an existing zip file?

Ideally with a file structure something like this.

```
df.zip
    >df_2020.02.28_144535.csv
    >df_2020.02.28_152010.csv
    >df_2020.02.28_171942.csv
    >df_2020.02.28_221014.csv
```

I hope that's clear enough. Thanks

Comment: Does this help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754165/python-pandas-create-zip-file-from-csv

Comment: There's an example on the pandas docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: Both of these get me closer but still not quite what I need. The answer at the link from @BenPap creates a new compressed file with one csv in it each time so I end up with a bunch of .gz files insted of a bunch of csv files. The code in the link from Adam works but it overwrites the csv file inside the zip each time its run. My goal is one compressed file with all the csv files inside.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are looking was enabled with the more recent pandas versions:

```py
zip_file = 'history/df.zip'
csv_name = 'df' + dt_string + '.csv'
df.to_csv(zip_file,
          encoding='utf-8',
          mode='a',
          compression=dict(method='zip',
                           archive_name=csv_name))
```

For details, see the docs on [DataFrame.to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)