# Python - Is there a good intermediary format to export mixed data to multiple filetypes?

Tags: python, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf, weasyprint, export-to-word

I have a model which generates output in the form of numpy arrays, text and plots. It currently holds this output as a dictionary.

There are requirements for the output to be presented in a variety of formats. Particularly, PDF, Word and Excel.

My solution has been to write all data to an HTML string, and export the HTML to a PDF using weasyprint. I would then export the table sections of the HTML to Excel. This works okay, but it's messy.

I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this? In my mind, perhaps there is a module which would allow you to store the information in a dictionary, and dictate its data type, then a process would handle it's formatting and exporting to various formats.

Comment: if you have as `numpy.array` then you can convert to `pandas.DataFrame` and use `dataframe.to_excel()` or `dataframe.to_csv()`. And even `dataframe.to_html()`. It has also `.to_xml()`, `.to_json()`, and even `.to_latex()` and this could be converted to PDF. But all this is only for table with data. Pandas doc: [How do I read and write tabular data?](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/02_read_write.html#min-tut-02-read-write)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to answer my own question, to demonstrate what I implemented as a solution.

Because the data formats were multimedia (text, numbers, plots), I made two approaches:

- A `Report` class which had the capability of exporting txt, html, docx and pdf
- A `Workbook` class, which had the capability of export xlsx and csv

Both classes inherited the same data structure, which was a nested dictionary containing numbers, and metadata. The `Report` class then grabbed additional text, and created plots from the data.

For example, the data resembled this structure:

```
data = {
    "Some Label":{
        "An Item":[1,2,3,4,5]
    }
}
```

The `Report` class built an HTML string using [Dominate](https://pypi.org/project/dominate/), and could either export as HTML by rendering this, PDF by feeding the rendered HTML into [WeasyPrint](https://weasyprint.org/), or to Docx (or some other format theoretically) by converting the rendered HTML to Docx via [PyPandoc](https://pypi.org/project/pypandoc/)

The `Workbook` class iterated through dictionaries of values and wrote groups of these values to Pandas dataframes, and exported them to a workbook using `pd.ExcelWriter`. The same dataframes could be exported to csv, and compressed into a zip file using an adapted solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754165/python-pandas-create-zip-file-from-csv).